# Matrix DSA Question (find mirrored matrix from the given matrices for each matrix)

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array

I want to know if there's an easier approach to solve this question: We have an input array that contains matrices like this: [[[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]],[[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[0,1,1]],[[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[1,0,0],[[0,1,1],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]]]. For each matrix we have to find if the mirrored matrix of it exists in the array and print the index, if not we print -1. So for this it would be: 3 2 1 0.

The only approach I can think of is to traverse the entire array for each matrix and then compare the cells for the matrix I'm checking for with the cells of the other matrices in the array. But that would be a lot of nested loops. So i was wondering if there was a better way to do this?

Comment: Do not tag this as `dsa`.  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.

Comment: Does the existing approach time-out, or violate any constraints?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.